# Sed - count lines by last two characters

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk

My input file:

```
    20110512075900 
    20110512075915 
    20110512075930  
    20110512075945  
    20110512075900  
    20110512080015
    20110512075930  
    20110512080000
    20110512075915
    20110512075945
    20110512075900
    20110512075930
    20110512075900
    20110512075915
```

I want to count number of lines from '...00'(last two characters) to next '...00'.
So, my output will be:

```
    4
    3
    3
    2
    2
```

I tried with sed:

```
    nrlinii=`sed -n '/^[0-9]00/,/^[0-9]45/ p' file.txt | wc -l `

    echo $nrlinii
```

But don't work.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: sed is not the best option for counting

Comment: Why is there a trailing "2" at the end of your expected output?

Comment: tuxman, consider accepting one of the given answers if your issue is already solved.

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk '{a++} /00$/ {print a; a=0} END{print a}' file
8
3
2
1
```

#### Explanation

- `{a++}` increments the counter `a`.
- `/00$/ {print a; a=0}` in case the line ends with `00` (`$` indicates end of line), then print the value and reset the counter.
- `END{print a}` print the counter from the last `00` up to the end.

Comment: +1; the OP's input data has inconsistent trailing whitespace, which is presumably why your sample output differs from the OP's. Here's a version where lines *before* the first `00` line are not counted: `awk '{a++} /00\s*$/ {if (numblocks++) print a; a=0} END {print a}' file`. To not count the lines *after* the last `00` line, remove `END {print a}`.

Answer (score 2):

Using bash only :

```
$ i=0; while read; do [[ $i -ne 0 ]] && [[ $REPLY =~ 00\ *$ ]] && { echo $i; i=0; }; let i=$i+1; done < test.txt ; echo $i
4
3
3
2
2
```

But I've posted this solution just for fun, I prefer to use `awk` as fedorqui's answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the best solution for me. Please excuse me for intruding, but I want you to help me with another problem. If $i >= 3,I want to keep only the line with '...00' and delete the other lines; and if $i < 3, do the same, but put '9999' on column two.So the output will be like this:                        20110512075900 
20110512075900  
20110512080000
20110512075900  9999
20110512075900  9999

Comment: @tuxman : You should open a new thread to post what you are trying to do (because you should try before asking question). In this way, we can answer without a feed of limited and unreadable comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (gnu SED & Shell):

```
sed '1{h;d};/00\s*$/!{H;$!d};x;s/.*/echo "&" | wc -l/ep;d' file
```

Collect groups of lines in the hold space. Then run `wc -l` against them.

Answer (score 1):

give this line a try:

```
awk -v RS='[0-9]*00\n' '$0=NF+1' file
```

Comment: +1 for elegance, but it also counts lines up to the *first* `00` line; heads-up for OSX users: won't work there, because `RS` doesn't support regexes.

Comment: @mklement0 yes, the first 00 line was counted. it could be fixed. I didn't since I **thought** it could be correct. :)...  about the OSX .. the question tagged with "linux". and yes, gawk is needed.

Comment: Completely understood re Linux; the only reason I mentioned it is for the benefit of other OSX users, who presumably, like me, often draw benefit from Linux answers as well. Since that doesn't always work, it's helpful to know when it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/00[[:space:]]*$/{ if (NR>1) print NR - prev; prev=NR}' file
4
3
3
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of hash would occur to me a natural way to count the items.

```
$ awk '{
    array[substr($1, 13, 2)]++
} END {
    for (num in array) {
        print num, array[num]
    }
}' input.txt
45 2
00 5
30 3
15 4
```